# Compiling a week's worth of tweets automatically?

Tags: automation, twitter

I'd like to be able to run a script that parsed through the twitter page and compiled a list of tweets for a given time period - one week to be more exact. Ideally it should return the results as a html list that could then be posted in a blog. Like here:

http://www.perezfox.com/2009/07/12/the-week-in-tweet-for-2009-07-12/

I'm sure there's a script out there that could do it, unless the guy does it manually (that would be a big pain!). If there is such a script forgive my ignorance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Twitter search API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search). For instance, this query returns my tweets between 2009-07-10 and 2009-07-17:

[`http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:tormodfj&since=2009-07-10&until=2009-07-17`](http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:tormodfj&since=2009-07-10&until=2009-07-17)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that's interested, I hacked together a quick PHP parser that will take the XML output of the above feed and turn it into a nice list. It's sensible if you post a lot of tweets to use the *rpp parameter*, so that your feed doesn't get clipped at 15. The maximum limit is 100. So by sticking this url into NetNewsWire (or equivalent feed reader):

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:yourTwitterAccountHere&since=2009-07-13&until=2009-07-19&rpp=100

and exporting the xml to a hard file, you can use this script:

```
<?php
$date = "";
$in = 'links.xml'; //tweets
file_exists($in) ? $xml = simplexml_load_file($in) : die ('Failed to open xml data.');
foreach($xml->entry as $item)
{
    $newdate = date("dS F", strtotime($item->published));
    if ($date == "")
    {
        echo "<h2>$newdate</h2>\n<ul>\n";
    }
    elseif ($newdate != $date)
    {
        echo "</ul>\n<h2>$newdate</h2>\n<ul>\n";
    }
    echo "<li>\n<p>" . $item->content ." <a href=\"" . $item->link['href'] . "\">*</a></p>\n</li>\n";
    $date = $newdate;
}
echo "</ul>\n";
?>
```